# Using a custom cache serializer with Azure App Fabric

Tags: caching, azure, azure-appfabric

The [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/hh552969.aspx) on MSDN says you can inherit from the `IDataCacheObjectSerializer` interface and update the configuration used to use custom serialization.

I can't find the `IDataCacheObjectSerializer` or the `SerializationProperties` element of the Configuration class in any DLL I've looked at, has anybody found these? Which version of the SDK are you using?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

This is available with the Azure Cache (Preview) release that is part of Azure SDK 1.7

You can look at my blog for more info: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jagan_peri/archive/2012/08/23/custom-serializer.aspx

Jagan Peri - Microsoft

Answer (score 0):

The first step in the link you've provided is '[First prepare the development environment to use Caching.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/gg278344.aspx)' which points at a set of instructions to follow first, which includes adding the necessary references

Comment: The `Microsoft.ApplicationServer.Caching.DataCacheFactoryConfiguration` in the assembly linked to `Microsoft.ApplicationServer.Caching.Client, Version=101.0.0.0` (Azure SDK 1.6) does not contain the `SerializationProperties` property or any sign of the interface. I've also tried the Azure SDK AppFabric SDK 1.5 and June 2011 CTP.

Comment: oops. you are correct of course. I'll try and find out, if/when I do I'll update my (incorrect) answer.